# delivering password via sms when signup

Tags: java, javascript, php, html, sms

I want to be able to send the login password as a SMS to the user. I'm looking for a free service like Google Voice API (last year). Can someone suggest a free service I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[phpgooglevoice](https://code.google.com/p/phpgooglevoice/)

I like "phpgooglevoice" if your only wanting sms sending.

Comment: Thanks Tyler's Lounge. Will the SMS be sent instantly? I've read that there is a delay when using the phpgooglevoice service (about 15 minutes)?

Comment: All the times I've used played with it.  It was anywhere from 30 seconds to 5 minute delay.  Keep in mind if you send more than 85 messages to the same phone number it will lock your google voice account for 24 hours. (learned that by playing with the code).  This is the only good solution to SMS that is free on the web from hours of searching.